# Trying to convert .log to .xml

Tags: php, python, xml, excel, powershell

I have been searching various ways to convert six 20 MB .log files to .xml

People have referred me to online converters, which don't convert.

Others say use developer tool of EXCEL, but

1. Data is not in correct format
2. It takes **forever** to copy and paste 20 MB of data onto EXCEL.

I am thinking of two options:

1. In powershell, store each line as an array, and then for reach line array, create another array, but the line formats are not consistent, as you will see
2. Research how to use php or python to convert into xml

Here is format of data

```
06/01 01:25:58 [2024:2588] 10.4.10.10<AgentInfo DomainID="8CB49C910AFB16720044B53CD014E7D9" AgentType="105" UserDomain="MYAWESOMEDOMAIN.ORG" LoginUser="admIN" ComputerDomain="myAWESOMEDOMAIN.org" ComputerName="AWESOMES001" PreferredGroup="My%20Company%5cServers%5cGUP" PreferredMode="1" KnownClientID="C35A5B1E0AFB16760019AE74888EA38A" HardwareKey="46E04E5469DC41949F33E73FDC0C5FCF" IsNPVDIClient="0" SiteDomainName=""/>

06/01 01:26:07 [2024:3280] 10.24.10.97<AgentInfo DomainID="8CB49C910AFB16720044B53CD014E7D9" AgentType="105" UserDomain="LocalComputer" LoginUser="Student%208" ComputerDomain="WORKGROUP" ComputerName="DC9Spartan" PreferredGroup="My%20Company%5cDefault%20Group" PreferredMode="1" HardwareKey="208B60B45CE2D02192B2FBB30CA1470A" SiteDomainName=""/>

06/01 01:26:07 [2024:3280] 10.24.10.97<AgentInfo DomainID="8CB49C910AFB16720044B53CD014E7D9" AgentType="105" UserDomain="LocalComputer" LoginUser="Student%208" ComputerDomain="WORKGROUP" ComputerName="DC9Spartan" PreferredGroup="My%20Company%5cDefault%20Group" PreferredMode="1" HardwareKey="208B60B45CE2D02192B2FBB30CA1470A" SiteDomainName=""/> AgentID=2C26221A0AFB167201AE7F6B29E365AD AgentType=105 ComputerID=1E6BFEF50AFB167201AE7F6BBA576A0C Hash Key=69C6250108E5B7FBB6ACF8294B6564FE

06/01 01:26:19 [2024:2748] 10.21.36.6<AgentInfo DomainID="8CB49C910AFB16720044B53CD014E7D9" AgentType="105" UserDomain="LocalComputer" LoginUser="student" ComputerDomain="WORKGROUP" ComputerName="DingDing9461JZ6" PreferredGroup="My%20Company%5cDefault%20Group" PreferredMode="1" HardwareKey="C6D4F00C9C2952182D8DAB03045C6E30" SiteDomainName=""/>

06/01 01:26:19 [2024:2748] 10.21.36.6<AgentInfo DomainID="8CB49C910AFB16720044B53CD014E7D9" AgentType="105" UserDomain="LocalComputer" LoginUser="student" ComputerDomain="WORKGROUP" ComputerName="DingDing9461JZ6" PreferredGroup="My%20Company%5cDefault%20Group" PreferredMode="1" HardwareKey="C6D4F00C9C2952182D8DAB03045C6E30" SiteDomainName=""/> AgentID=BBF24AB00AFB167200D94A8E46E57D3C AgentType=105 ComputerID=1B4EF5B30AFB167200D94A8E8EBB8E65 Hash Key=6BAC96603C7495DE08E5F305EEF310EE

06/01 01:26:33 [2024:3376] 5 Server returned: 500 Internal Server Error

06/01 01:26:33 [2024:3376] 10.16.64.16<AgentInfo DomainID="ACD6E7230AFB160401B335F917AFF5BE" AgentType="105" UserDomain="LocalComputer" LoginUser="admin" ComputerDomain="myAWESOMEDOMAIN.org" ComputerName="LLR0MGVY" PreferredGroup="My%20Company%5cDefault%20Group" PreferredMode="1" HardwareKey="EFDBD800D66488B08936A51F19B5496A" IsNPVDIClient="0" SiteDomainName=""/>--FAILED
```

I am trying to correlate IP address with the other data like `DomainID`, etc.
It gets complicated because there is line that has some Server error message, and then NEXT line lists IP address,

I am thinking if I can get into XML format, it would be easier to query the data. Or is there another approach to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Thank you

## OUTPUT

I'm not too familiar with XML, but I guess the output I am looking for is

```
<Date>06/01 01:25:58
<ID>[2024:2588]
<IP>10.4.10.10</IP>
<AgentInfo>
<DomainID></DomainID>
<AgentType></AgentType>
<UserDomain></UserDomain>
<LoginUser></LoginUser>
etc, etc, the other fields within AgentInfo
</AgentInfo>
</ID>
</Date>


<Date>06/01 01:26:33
<ID>[2024:3376]
<IP>10.16.64.16</IP>
<Msg>5 Server returned: 500 Internal Server Error</Msg>
</ID>
</Date>
```

Comment: Show the output you want

Comment: @splash58 Post was updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll offer a PowerShell solution using RegEx, `ConvertFrom-StringData` (probably could have used XML typing to convert the AgentInfo, but this was simpler for my solution), and a HashTable of objects to collect the records into objects, then I convert that to XML, and clean that up because PowerShell's `ConvertTo-XML` cmdlet is overly verbose imho.

```psh
$InputData = Get-Content 'C:\Path\To\File.log'

$Records = @{}
$InputData | ?{$_ -match "^(?<Date>\d{2}\/\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}) (?<ID>\[.+?\]) (?<IP>\S+)\<AgentInfo (?<AgentInfo>.+?)\/\>" -or $_ -match "^(?<Date>\d{2}\/\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}) (?<ID>\[.+?\]) (?<Msg>.+)"}|
    %{$Record = [pscustomobject]@{
            [string]'Date'=$Matches['Date']
            [string]'ID'=$Matches['ID']
            [string]'IP'=$Matches['IP']
            [string]'Msg'=$Matches['Msg']
            'AgentInfo'=New-Object PSObject -Prop ($Matches['AgentInfo'] -replace '(?<=") ',"`r`n" | ConvertFrom-StringData)
        }
    $record
    If($Matches['ID'] -notin $Records.Keys){
        $Records.Add($Matches['ID'], $Record)
        }Else{
            $Record|Get-Member -MemberType Properties | Where{![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($Record.($_.Name))} | ForEach{$Records."$($Matches['ID'])"|Add-Member "$($_.Name)" $Record.$($_.Name) -Force}
        }
}

$records.Values|select Date,ID,IP,Msg,AgentInfo|convertto-xml -Depth 2 -NoTypeInformation -as Stream|%{$_ -replace 'Property Name="(.+?)(?=">)"(.*)Property(?=>)','$1$2$1' -replace 'Property Name="(.+?)"(?= />)','$1' -replace '<Property Name="(.+?)">','<$1>' -replace '</Property>','</AgentInfo>'} | Set-Content C:\Path\To\OutFile.xml
```

That will output:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>  
<Objects>  
<Object>  
  <Date>06/01 01:26:19</Date>  
  <ID>[2024:2748]</ID>  
  <IP>10.21.36.6</IP>  
  <Msg />  
  <AgentInfo>  
    <LoginUser>"student"</LoginUser>  
    <ComputerDomain>"WORKGROUP"</ComputerDomain>  
    <ComputerName>"DingDing9461JZ6"</ComputerName>  
    <DomainID>"8CB49C910AFB16720044B53CD014E7D9"</DomainID>  
    <HardwareKey>"C6D4F00C9C2952182D8DAB03045C6E30"</HardwareKey>  
    <SiteDomainName>""</SiteDomainName>  
    <PreferredGroup>"My%20Company%5cDefault%20Group"</PreferredGroup>  
    <AgentType>"105"</AgentType>  
    <PreferredMode>"1"</PreferredMode>  
    <UserDomain>"LocalComputer"</UserDomain>  
  </AgentInfo>  
</Object>  
<Object>  
  <Date>06/01 01:25:58</Date>  
  <ID>[2024:2588]</ID>  
  <IP>10.4.10.10</IP>  
  <Msg />  
  <AgentInfo>  
    <LoginUser>"admIN"</LoginUser>  
    <IsNPVDIClient>"0"</IsNPVDIClient>  
    <ComputerDomain>"myAWESOMEDOMAIN.org"</ComputerDomain>  
    <ComputerName>"AWESOMES001"</ComputerName>  
    <DomainID>"8CB49C910AFB16720044B53CD014E7D9"</DomainID>  
    <HardwareKey>"46E04E5469DC41949F33E73FDC0C5FCF"</HardwareKey>  
    <SiteDomainName>""</SiteDomainName>  
    <PreferredGroup>"My%20Company%5cServers%5cGUP"</PreferredGroup>  
    <AgentType>"105"</AgentType>  
    <KnownClientID>"C35A5B1E0AFB16760019AE74888EA38A"</KnownClientID>  
    <PreferredMode>"1"</PreferredMode>  
    <UserDomain>"MYAWESOMEDOMAIN.ORG"</UserDomain>  
  </AgentInfo>  
</Object>  
<Object>  
  <Date>06/01 01:26:07</Date>  
  <ID>[2024:3280]</ID>  
  <IP>10.24.10.97</IP>  
  <Msg />  
  <AgentInfo>  
    <LoginUser>"Student%208"</LoginUser>  
    <ComputerDomain>"WORKGROUP"</ComputerDomain>  
    <ComputerName>"DC9Spartan"</ComputerName>  
    <DomainID>"8CB49C910AFB16720044B53CD014E7D9"</DomainID>  
    <HardwareKey>"208B60B45CE2D02192B2FBB30CA1470A"</HardwareKey>  
    <SiteDomainName>""</SiteDomainName>  
    <PreferredGroup>"My%20Company%5cDefault%20Group"</PreferredGroup>  
    <AgentType>"105"</AgentType>  
    <PreferredMode>"1"</PreferredMode>  
    <UserDomain>"LocalComputer"</UserDomain>  
  </AgentInfo>  
</Object>  
<Object>  
  <Date>06/01 01:26:33</Date>  
  <ID>[2024:3376]</ID>  
  <IP>10.16.64.16</IP>  
  <Msg>5 Server returned: 500 Internal Server Error</Msg>  
  <AgentInfo>  
    <LoginUser>"admin"</LoginUser>  
    <IsNPVDIClient>"0"</IsNPVDIClient>  
    <ComputerDomain>"myAWESOMEDOMAIN.org"</ComputerDomain>  
    <ComputerName>"LLR0MGVY"</ComputerName>  
    <DomainID>"ACD6E7230AFB160401B335F917AFF5BE"</DomainID>  
    <HardwareKey>"EFDBD800D66488B08936A51F19B5496A"</HardwareKey>  
    <SiteDomainName>""</SiteDomainName>  
    <PreferredGroup>"My%20Company%5cDefault%20Group"</PreferredGroup>  
    <AgentType>"105"</AgentType>  
    <PreferredMode>"1"</PreferredMode>  
    <UserDomain>"LocalComputer"</UserDomain>  
  </AgentInfo>  
</Object>  
</Objects>
```

That is pretty close to what you wanted as your output.

Comment: Shouldn't the first line be `$InputData = Get-Content 'C:\Path\To\File.log'`

Comment: I am trying to understand how `$_ -match "^(?` works. I thought that `^` means not, as in `[^abc]` means `not a, b, or c` .... trying to figure this out as well .......

Comment: Ok I think `^` means "begins with"

Comment: Yes on the `$InputData =` bit, I updated it to reflect that. Sorry, I wasn't importing from a file, I pasted your example in as a herestring and split/parsed that. As for `^`, while inside square brackets it does mean NOT, but when used like I did it does in fact mean the beginning of a string or line

Answer (score 1):

I would use Python for sure.

Something like this:

```
import sys


inFile = sys.argv[1]
inFile = open(inFile,'r')
parser = inFile.readlines()
outFile = open('[your_path]\\converted.xml', 'w')      

for i in parser:
   slice = i.split(' ') #split each line at spaces and do stuff with each slice
   outFile.write("<date>" + slice[0] + "</date>" + '\n')
   outFile.write("<time>" + slice[1] + "</time>" + '\n')
and so on...
```

Answer (score 1):

The XMLWriter Api is an XML Api designed for this kind of work. Here is an example to get you started:

```
$xml = new XMLWriter();
$xml->openUri($output);
$xml->startDocument();
$xml->setIndent(2);
$xml->startElement('log');

$file = fopen($input, 'r');
while (FALSE !== ($line = fgets($file))) {
  if (FALSE !== ($p = strpos($line, '<'))) {
    $xml->startElement('line');
    $xml->writeElement('date', substr($line, 0, $p - 1));
    $xml->writeRaw(substr($line, $p));
    $xml->endElement();
  }
}
$xml->endElement();
$xml->endDocument();
$xml->flush();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<log>
 <line>
  <date>06/01 01:25:58 [2024:2588] 10.4.10.1</date>
<AgentInfo DomainID="8CB49C910AFB16720044B53CD014E7D9" AgentType="105" UserDomain="MYAWESOMEDOMAIN.ORG" LoginUser="admIN" ComputerDomain="myAWESOMEDOMAIN.org" ComputerName="AWESOMES001" PreferredGroup="My%20Company%5cServers%5cGUP" PreferredMode="1" KnownClientID="C35A5B1E0AFB16760019AE74888EA38A" HardwareKey="46E04E5469DC41949F33E73FDC0C5FCF" IsNPVDIClient="0" SiteDomainName=""/>
</line>
...
```

You will need a document element and elements for each entry/line are a good idea. I split it only into the two basic parts. You will need to add more logic (maybe Regex) depending on you target XML format. The agent info is an XML element/document, so it can be copied (raw) to the target XML.

XMLWriter is not an API exclusive to PHP, you will find implementations for many languages.